# using nohup for lammps command

Tags: networking, cmd, mpiexec, lammps

I am running Lammps on a remote windows machine using MPICH2 to run in parallel, but sometimes, the connection drops and simulation exits.
I used this command, but it is not working:

```
nohup mpiexec.exe -np 8 -localonly lmp_mpi.exe -in ionicdata.in &
```

It is working without "nohup".

What is that I am missing here?

Comment: Microsoft Windows does not have a `nohup` command. From where are you getting it?

Comment: reallly??? someone on a mailing list told me, but I now know it was my misinterpretation. So, what should be done for windows?

Comment: Is this the `mpiexec` for Windows HPC? Have you checked the event logs?

Comment: No, it is a usual win. 7 and I am using mpiexec to run parallel. I checked my software log, but the reason is connection dropping.

Comment: I do not know. I would recommend a query on the Microsoft forum. https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowshpcmpi

Comment: Have you been through these messages? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?query=mpiexec%20dropped%20connection&ac=5